# Trocar valor de um array quando nulo

Tags: php, array, null

Tenho um WebService em PHP que me retorna um JSON com valores de um banco de dados mySQL.

Preciso que, em um Array, sempre que houver um valor nulo (quando `= null`), seja trocado por branco (`= ""`).

Estou fazendo dessa maneira, mas sem sucesso.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8;");

include('connectdb.php');

$something = $_GET['cod'];
$sqlcode = mysql_query("Select descricao, cliente, local from terminal_cartao Where     descricao='$something'");
$sqlcode2 = mysql_query("Select descricao, cliente, local from terminal_cartao");

$jsonObj= array();

if($something == 'all')
{

while($result=mysql_fetch_object($sqlcode2))
{
$jsonObj[] = $result;
}

}

else{
while($result=mysql_fetch_object($sqlcode))
{
$jsonObj[] = $result;
}
}

foreach ($jsonObj as $key => $value) {
if ($value === null) {
    $jsonObj[$key] = ""; 
}
}

$final_res =json_encode($jsonObj);
echo $final_res;
exit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Itere pelo array verificando e trocando os valores:

```
foreach ($jsonObj as $k1 => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k2 => $value) {
        if ($value === null) {
            $jsonObj[$k1]->$k2 = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: não funcionou, editei minha resposta e coloquei o codigo completo. O que pode estar errado?

Comment: Editei a resposta agora para array bidimensional.

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in `$jsonObj[$k1][$k2] = "";` ou em pt: Não é possível usar o objeto do tipo stdClass como array em `$jsonObj[$k1][$k2] = "";`

Comment: Editei novamente, não havia visto que eram objetos.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 5):

Vou deixar uma alternativa não apenas mais eficiente (loops aninhados são ruins) como também flexível o suficiente para trabalhar com arrays de infinitas dimensões:

```
function modify( $param ) {

    if( is_array( $param ) ) {
        return array_map( __FUNCTION__, $param );
    }

    if( $param === NULL ) {
        $param = '';
    }

    return $param;
}
```

Caso não saiba, [array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map) aplica uma função sobre cada elemento de um array. Para cada array que a invocação corrente encontrar, a função vai ser chamada de novo, de novo e de novo, recursivamente, nos bastidores.

Quando não houverem mais arrays para recursar, **$param** não é mais um array e a função começa a trabalhar, no caso, substituindo o valor e tipo NULL por uma string vazia.

*Et voilà*

Answer (score 4):

Outra alternativa é aplicar uma condicional na query SQL. Assim não haveria necessidade em modificar nada no PHP.

escopo

```
IF(col_name IS NULL,"",col_name) AS col_name
```

Exemplo prático usando parte do seu código

```
$sqlcode = mysql_query("SELECT descricao, IF(cliente IS NULL,"",cliente) AS cliente, IF(local IS NULL,"",local) AS local from terminal_cartao WHERE descricao='$something'");
```

*No exemplo prático, desconsiderei a coluna "descricao" devido ao uso da mesma na condição WHERE.